# IBM recognizing failed

Tags: python, speech-recognition, ibm-watson

I'm making a voice changer program, and I'm using speech_recognition's IBM Watson Speech to Text program to recognize speech. However, I ran into some problem.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Adjusting for background noise. One second")
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

IBM_USERNAME = "apikey"  # IBM Speech to Text usernames are strings of the form XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
IBM_PASSWORD = " this is my apikey"  # IBM Speech to Text passwords are mixed-case alphanumeric strings
try:
    print("IBM Speech to Text thinks you said " + r.recognize_ibm(audio, username=IBM_USERNAME, password=IBM_PASSWORD))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("IBM Speech to Text could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from IBM Speech to Text service; {0}".format(e))
```

But,

```
Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276, Oct  5 2020, 11:29:23) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
===================== RESTART: Users/xxxxx/v1 ibm.py ====================
Adjusting for background noise. One second
Say something!
Could not request results from IBM Speech to Text service; recognition connection failed: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)
>>>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall with an HTTPS proxy?

Comment: No, I'm at my home computer.

Comment: IBM API's typically have an access link. On top of the user and pass, there might be some link you need to access the API. This is just with my experience with text to speech.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use the speech_recognition library, but to no avail. So, I used the ibm_watson library and it worked!